# JavaFX 8: javafx.fxml.LoadException - fxmlLoader.load() doesn't work, but fxmlLoader.getController() does

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

I have a LoadException when trying to load a controller from a FXML file. Here is the FXML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Interface.ChangeProjoOrderController">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane>
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <items>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

The Window that loads the FXML is:

```html
package Interface;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import Engine.PackageLight.Projector;

public class ChangeProjoOrderWindow
{
 private MainWindowController mainController;
 
 private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = null;
 private VBox root = null;//TODO uncomment me
 //private Parent root = null;//TODO delete me
 private ChangeProjoOrderController controller;
 private Scene scene;
 private Stage stage;
 
 private static final Logger logUI = Logger.getLogger("UI");
 
 
 ChangeProjoOrderWindow(MainWindowController c)
 {
  mainController = c;
  
  try
  {
   fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/projectorOrder.fxml"));
   root = (VBox)fxmlLoader.load();//TODO uncomment me
   //root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();//TODO delete me
   
   //XXX DO NOT do this !! The controller will stay null (uninitialized)
   //root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/orderProjo.fxml"));
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
   logUI.severe("Error: Cannot load the FXML file 'projectorOrder.fxml'.");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  controller = fxmlLoader.<ChangeProjoOrderController>getController();
  if(controller == null)
   System.err.println("controller is null");
  scene = new Scene(root);
  
  System.exit(0);
  
  stage = new Stage();
  stage.setOnCloseRequest(we -> 
  {
   // Application termination event
   c.setChangeProjectorOrderDisableStatus(false);
   stage.close();
   logUI.fine("orderProjo terminated.");
  });
  
  mainController.windows.executePreChangeProjectorOrder();
  
  stage.setTitle("Modifier l'ordre des projecteurs");
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();
  
  controller.setMainController(mainController);
  controller.setStage(stage);
 }
 
 protected void setProjectors(ArrayList<Projector> projectors){controller.setProjectors(projectors);}
}
```

And here is the Controller:

```html
package Interface;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import Engine.PackageLight.Projector;

public class ChangeProjoOrderController implements Initializable
{
 /*@FXML private Button up;
 @FXML private Button down;
 @FXML private Button newProjo;
 @FXML private Button remove;
 @FXML private Button duplicate;
 @FXML private Button edit;
 @FXML private Button ok;
 @FXML private Button cancel;
 
 @FXML private GridPane gridPane;*/
 
 private MainWindowController mainController;
 private Stage stage;
 
 private ArrayList<Projector> projectorList = null;
 
 private static final Logger logUI = Logger.getLogger("UI");
 
 @Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
 {
  /*cancel.setOnAction(event ->
  {
   logUI.info("cancel");
   mainController.setChangeProjectorOrderDisableStatus(false);
   stage.close();
  });
  
  ok.setOnAction(event ->
  {
   logUI.info("ok");
   mainController.setChangeProjectorOrderDisableStatus(false);
   stage.close();
  });*/
  
  initProjectors();
 }
 
 private void initProjectors()
 {
  for(int i=0; i<projectorList.size(); i++)
  {
   Label curr = new Label(Integer.toString(i));
   GridPane.setColumnIndex(curr, 0);
   GridPane.setRowIndex(curr, i);
  }
 }
 
 protected void setMainController(MainWindowController c){mainController = c;}
 protected void setStage(Stage s){stage = s;}
 protected void setProjectors(ArrayList<Projector> projectors){projectorList = projectors;}
}
```

And finally, the stack trace:

```html
INFO [UI] Interface.Windows - changeProjoOrder
  Changing the order of the projectors...
[0m[31m[1mSEVERE [UI] Interface.ChangeProjoOrderWindow - <init>
  Error: Cannot load the FXML file 'projectorOrder.fxml'.
[0mjavafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/filou/workspace/java/syncart/bin/Interface/fxml/projectorOrder.fxml

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2583)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2413)
 at Interface.ChangeProjoOrderWindow.<init>(ChangeProjoOrderWindow.java:35)
 at Interface.Windows.changeProjoOrder(Windows.java:151)
 at Interface.MainWindowController.changeProjoOrder(MainWindowController.java:308)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$341(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$$Lambda$398/1949840625.handle(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
 at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$357/365619965.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$42/1327763628.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Interface.ChangeProjoOrderController.initProjectors(ChangeProjoOrderController.java:58)
 at Interface.ChangeProjoOrderController.initialize(ChangeProjoOrderController.java:53)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
 ... 61 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$341(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$$Lambda$398/1949840625.handle(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
 at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
 at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$357/365619965.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$42/1327763628.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
 ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
 at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:336)
 at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:194)
 at Interface.ChangeProjoOrderWindow.<init>(ChangeProjoOrderWindow.java:50)
 at Interface.Windows.changeProjoOrder(Windows.java:151)
 at Interface.MainWindowController.changeProjoOrder(MainWindowController.java:308)
 ... 56 more
```

Ok. Now the problem seems to come from the line

```html
root = (VBox)fxmlLoader.load();//TODO uncomment me
```

which causes an IOException. But after, the lines

```html
controller = fxmlLoader.<ChangeProjoOrderController>getController();
  if(controller == null)
   System.err.println("controller is null");
```

do not print a "controller is null". So the controller is properly loaded, but the "root" isn't. I've checked the "@FXML" tags (which I commented out finally... to no avail), the "fx:controller" in the FXML file (it is written the same as another file that works, i.e. Interface.xxx), I re-did the window with SceneBuilder 2.0 from scratch to be sure the FXML is well-generated, I tried to set the "root" as a "Parent" or "VBox" and I compared my files with other files that work.

The window that is built do not appear.

I'm using:
LUbuntu 3.13.0-46-generic,
JavaFX 8 u40,
Eclipse Mars Milestone 3 (4.5.0M3) Build id 20141113-0320,
JavaFx SceneBuilder 2.0-b20

So why have I this exception ? Where does it come from ?

I'm not sure if this is clear, I've been in this code for a long time now :P If any more information is needed, please tell me; I'll provide it.

Thanks

Comment: `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));` maybe this works. Have you made your UI with scenebuilder btw? Because if you do then you don't have to declare a `VBox` in the `ChangeProjoOrderWindow` class, that all will only be in the .fxml file.

Comment: Yes, I built the interface using SceneBuilder 2. The call
    fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/projectorOrder.fxml"));
is correct, as I'm using the 'fxml' folder to store the FXML files. I've tried your solution, but didn't work. I find the solution, though. See below. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace says that the exception comes from line 58 of `ChangeProjoOrderController`.

I'm guessing that this is

```
for(int i=0; i<projectorList.size(); i++)
```

which makes sense, since you initialize

```
private ArrayList<Projector> projectorList = null;
```

and don't change its value, at least until after the FXML is loaded (and the `initalize()` method is called).

Comment: Ok, I found the error. Thanks to your hint !
I was calling a method that made a call to a method in 'ChangeProjoOrderWindow'. The thing is, the initial call was made from the constructor of 'ChangeProjoOrderWindow', so the object wasn't created yet !
Now, I make the call to this method AFTER the constructor is done (so not from the constructor), and it works !

Thanks again for the help !